# Overflow: auto in Firefox not working the same as in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

Depending on where you open this HTML, you will see the vertical scroll bar. In Chrome the table doesn't exceeds 180 pixels it has a height. However, in Firefox it expands and exceeds the 180 pixels it has as height. The div with id **detailFee** has the style of overflow: auto and the height and width are 100%. Is there any solution so the table in Firefox has the same look as Chrome?

Firefox
[image: Firefox table]

Chrome
[image: Chrome table]

```html
<style>
  #detailFee {
    background: window;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1;
    border-color: lightgray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>

<table
  width="800px"
  height="180px"
  style="background-color: lightblue; border-collapse: collapse"
>
  <tbody>
    <tr height="100%">
      <td>
        <div id="detailFee">
          <table
            style="height: 100%"
            width="100%"
            cellspacing="0"
            cellpadding="0"
            border="1"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr height="19px">
                <td
                  style="width: 15px; flex-flow: column nowrap; display: none"
                  nowrap=""
                  align="center"
                >
                  +
                </td>
                <td
                  style="width: 15px; flex-flow: column"
                  nowrap=""
                  align="center"
                >
                  -
                </td>
                <td width="60%" nowrap="" align="left">Test</td>
                <td width="110px" nowrap="" align="right">Test</td>
                <td width="85px" nowrap="" align="right">Test</td>
                <td width="85px" nowrap="" align="right">Test</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td
                  style="display: none"
                  valign="middle"
                  nowrap=""
                  align="center"
                >
                  +
                </td>
                <td
                  style="display: table-cell"
                  valign="middle"
                  nowrap=""
                  align="center"
                >
                  Test
                </td>
                <td nowrap="">Test</td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="display: table-row">
                <td nowrap=""></td>
                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                  <table
                    width="100%"
                    cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="0"
                    border="1"
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="display: none" nowrap="" align="center">
                          +
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style="display: table-cell"
                          nowrap=""
                          align="center"
                        >
                          Test
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="display: table-row">
                        <td nowrap=""></td>
                        <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                          <table
                            width="100%"
                            cellspacing="0"
                            cellpadding="0"
                            border="1"
                          >
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td
                                  style="display: none"
                                  valign="top"
                                  nowrap=""
                                  align="center"
                                >
                                  +
                                </td>
                                <td
                                  style=""
                                  valign="top"
                                  nowrap=""
                                  align="center"
                                >
                                  -
                                </td>
                                <td width="60%" valign="top">Test</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="display: none">
                                <td nowrap=""></td>
                                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                                  <table
                                    width="100%"
                                    height="100%"
                                    cellspacing="0"
                                    cellpadding="0"
                                    border="1"
                                  >
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td width="30%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                                        <td width="30%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                                        <td
                                          width="110px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Assessed
                                        </td>
                                        <td
                                          width="85px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Paid
                                        </td>
                                        <td
                                          width="85px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Due
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="display: table-row">
                                <td nowrap=""></td>
                                <td colspan="6" nowrap="">Test</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="display: table-row">
                <td nowrap=""></td>
                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                  <table
                    width="100%"
                    cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="0"
                    border="1"
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="display: none" nowrap="" align="center">
                          +
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style="display: table-cell"
                          nowrap=""
                          align="center"
                        >
                          Test
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="display: table-row">
                        <td nowrap=""></td>
                        <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                          <table
                            width="100%"
                            cellspacing="0"
                            cellpadding="0"
                            border="1"
                          >
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td
                                  style="display: none"
                                  valign="top"
                                  nowrap=""
                                  align="center"
                                >
                                  +
                                </td>
                                <td
                                  style=""
                                  valign="top"
                                  nowrap=""
                                  align="center"
                                >
                                  -
                                </td>
                                <td width="60%" valign="top">Test</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="display: none">
                                <td nowrap=""></td>
                                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                                  <table
                                    width="100%"
                                    height="100%"
                                    cellspacing="0"
                                    cellpadding="0"
                                    border="1"
                                  >
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td width="30%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                                        <td width="30%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                                        <td
                                          width="110px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Assessed
                                        </td>
                                        <td
                                          width="85px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Paid
                                        </td>
                                        <td
                                          width="85px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Due
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="display: table-row">
                                <td nowrap=""></td>
                                <td colspan="6" nowrap="">Test</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="display: table-row">
                <td nowrap=""></td>
                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                  <table
                    width="100%"
                    cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="0"
                    border="1"
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="display: none" nowrap="" align="center">
                          +
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style="display: table-cell"
                          nowrap=""
                          align="center"
                        >
                          Test
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="display: table-row">
                        <td nowrap=""></td>
                        <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                          <table
                            width="100%"
                            cellspacing="0"
                            cellpadding="0"
                            border="1"
                          >
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td
                                  style="display: none"
                                  valign="top"
                                  nowrap=""
                                  align="center"
                                >
                                  +
                                </td>
                                <td
                                  style=""
                                  valign="top"
                                  nowrap=""
                                  align="center"
                                >
                                  -
                                </td>
                                <td width="60%" valign="top">Test</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="display: none">
                                <td nowrap=""></td>
                                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                                  <table
                                    width="100%"
                                    height="100%"
                                    cellspacing="0"
                                    cellpadding="0"
                                    border="1"
                                  >
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td nowrap="">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td width="30%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                                        <td width="30%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                                        <td
                                          width="110px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Assessed
                                        </td>
                                        <td
                                          width="85px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Paid
                                        </td>
                                        <td
                                          width="85px"
                                          nowrap=""
                                          align="right"
                                        >
                                          Total Due
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="display: table-row">
                                <td nowrap=""></td>
                                <td colspan="6" nowrap="">Test</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="display: table-row">
                <td nowrap=""></td>
                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                  <table
                    width="100%"
                    cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="0"
                    border="1"
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="display: none" nowrap="" align="center">
                          +
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style="display: table-cell"
                          nowrap=""
                          align="center"
                        >
                          Test
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" nowrap="">Test</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="display: none">
                <td nowrap=""></td>
                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                  <table
                    width="100%"
                    cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="0"
                    border="1"
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td nowrap="" align="center">+</td>
                        <td style="display: none" nowrap="" align="center">
                          -
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" nowrap="">Jointly/Severally Fees</td>
                        <td width="110px" nowrap="" align="right">$0.00</td>
                        <td width="85px" nowrap="" align="right">$0.00</td>
                        <td width="85px" nowrap="" align="right">$0.00</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td
                  style="display: none"
                  valign="middle"
                  nowrap=""
                  align="center"
                >
                  +
                </td>
                <td
                  style="display: table-cell"
                  valign="middle"
                  nowrap=""
                  align="center"
                >
                  Test
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="display: none">
                <td nowrap=""></td>
                <td colspan="4" nowrap="">
                  <table
                    width="100%"
                    cellspacing="0"
                    cellpadding="0"
                    border="1"
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td nowrap="" align="center">+</td>
                        <td style="display: none" nowrap="" align="center">
                          -
                        </td>
                        <td width="60%" nowrap="">Jointly/Severally Fees</td>
                        <td width="110px" nowrap="" align="right">$0.00</td>
                        <td width="85px" nowrap="" align="right">$0.00</td>
                        <td width="85px" nowrap="" align="right">$0.00</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Here I have the same result in Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox

```
        body{
            position :absolute;
        }
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        #mainContainer{
            height:180px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
        #detailFee {
            background: window;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            border-style: inset;
            border-width: 1;
            border-color: lightgray;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

Try to put the main table inside a "mainContainer" div like this...

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<table
  width="800px"
  height="180px"
  style="background-color: lightblue; border-collapse: collapse"
>
```

And at the end of your html :

```
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Already added a style. However, I notice that if I add the height: auto attribute, it removes the scrollbar. The idea is for the div to be the same height as the td. In Chrome the overflow:auto sets the scrollbar as expected, the issue is in Firefox when it doesn't add the scrollbar

Comment: @ResidentZero9999 Sorry, i misunderstood your goal so. Thanks for your comment.